# Upgrading Linux kernel module without reboot

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way to upgrade linux driver module without rebooting the system ?

Comment: What kind of module are we talking about here? A central component?

Comment: a dynamically loadable module

Comment: That’s not helping. If you can, please name it or at least describe what it does. Preferably with `lsmod` output included.

Comment: Which specific module do you mean? Oracle claims [Ksplice](https://www.ksplice.com/) can avoid reboots, but I've never tried it.

Comment: this is a character driver module that has to be upgraded with latest versions without rebooting the system and minimal downtime.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you’re not that forthcoming with the info, let’s keep it theoretical.

**Yes**, a kernel module can be unloaded. It’s quite easy, too:

```
localhost ~ # modprobe kcopy
localhost ~ # lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
kcopy                   5124  0
iTCO_wdt                4967  0
lpc_ich                13224  0
mfd_core                3041  1 lpc_ich
localhost ~ # modprobe -r kcopy
```

As you can see in the listing, the kernel module wasn’t in use (counter at 0). If a module is in use (e.g. a filesystem driver which has a mounted filesystem), it cannot be unloaded.

**But** this all depends on the kernel being built with support to remove modules:

```
[*] Enable loadable module support  --->
    --- Enable loadable module support
    [*]   Module unloading
```

(Symbol: `MODULE_UNLOAD`)

There’s also support of forced removal, but it must not be used on production systems.